# Custom simple membership provider adding row

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, simplemembership

I have a custom `SimpleMembershipProvider` and i have defined all tables that the `SimpleMembershipProvider` requires, like webpages_Membership:

```
[Table("webpages_Membership")]
public class Membership
{
    public Membership()
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>();
        OAuthMemberships = new List<OAuthMembership>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
    public bool? IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }
    public int PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(128)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(128)]
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ICollection<OAuthMembership> OAuthMemberships { get; set; }
}
```

But how do i add a record in this table within the `Seed()` method in the configuration.cs file that migrations creates when enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the custom membership provider correctly configured in the web.config you should be able to add a record in the Seed method by doing this.

```
 var membership = (MyMembershipNamespace.SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
 membership.CreateUserAndAccount("test", "password");
```

Comment: Hi, that seems to work, but how come PasswordVerificationToken isn't filled in the database?

Comment: The PasswordVerificationToken is only filled in when you call GeneratePasswordResetToken [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548086(v=vs.111).aspx], which is used for the password reset process.